# scp files from batch account user's folder to local machine

Tags: linux, scp, remote-server

I am a part of a batch account or a headless user account on a remote machine. To ssh passwordless to the batch account, I have appended my .ssh/authorized_keys  to the batch account's .ssh/authorized_keys. This ssh as the batch account user to the remote machine works fine.

Now, I have the need to copy certain files from this headless user account's directories to my machine. So, whenever I do

```
scp batch_user_account@remote_machine:file_address local_machine_address
```

it asks for the batch_user_account's password, which I am not aware of.

I also tried to offer my private key as identity file like:

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa batch_user_account@remote_machine:file_address local_machine_address
```

But this also gives me a permission denied error to the batch user account's folder.
Am I doing something incorrect here?
Can anyone guide me here?
Thank you.

Comment: You do not copy your .ssh/authorized_keys you need to append one of your public keys, where the private part is private to the machine you are ssh from.

Comment: can you `ssh batch_user_account@remote_machine` ?

Comment: What is the error for `scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa batch_user_account@remote_machine:file_address local_machine_address` ?

Comment: @richard  Yes, I can ssh as 'ssh batch_user_account@remote_machine'. The error that I am getting is Permission denied for the directory which I intend to copy to my local machine.

Comment: so when you ssh, can you read the content of the files in this directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same task (of copying files from batch user account on remote machine to another machine A) by choosing a different machine B instead of A. I wanted to see if the error reproduced. To ssh passwordless to the batch account on remote machine through this new machine, I appended my .ssh/authorized_keys to the batch account's .ssh/authorized_keys. On this new machine, the command

```
scp batch_user_account@remote_machine:file_address local_machine_address
```

worked fine. So, I realized there were permission issues that I had to solve. When I changed the permissions on the file destination machine, it worked.